# Accessing apis over https with ruby

Tags: ruby, api, ssl, https, google-api

I am writing a script to do price tracking using the google shopping api. When I hit this url with curl, or a web browser, it loads the data.

https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=AIzaSyC24EXbQZ1X7KmaKLJ-Bd9SKgOx4x9ob-M&country=US&q=digital+camera

However, when I use this ruby script

```
require "rubygems"
require "net/https"

@url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=AIzaSyCGGKfldgrPQsXAJw5Dbn1M3QWZ9vqVyBQ&country=US&q=digital+camera'
uri = URI.parse @url
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
http.use_ssl = true 
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http.ca_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "./cacert.pem")
http.start { http.request_get(uri.path) {|res| print res.body } }
```

I get this error:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
 }
}
```

My theory is that the error is coming from how my ruby code is improperly using https.
The cacert.pem is from curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
What do I need to do to access the api over https?

Answer (score 0):

The error looks pretty self-explanatory to me. What's the daily limit? How many requests are you making?

Comment: I have made 8 requests since I signed up yesterday. The daily limit is 2.5k requests a day, with a 1 request per second limit.